# `cat -v` for non-printing non-ascii UTF characters

Tags: cat, unicode, control-characters

`cat` has a `-v` option which converts non-printing characters to their caret notation (which is useful if we don't want the terminal to interpret the control characters literally in `cat` output).

But as I understand, the caret notation only applies to non-printing characters in the ASCII alphabet. So what about the non-printing characters in UTF that do not fall in ASCII (e.g., https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/category/Cc)? What notation will `cat -v` use to display these?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can generate a file containing the first 256 Unicode characters in UTF-8 with:

```
python3 -c 'for x in range(0,255): print(chr(x), end="")' > unicode-file
```

That includes the non-ASCII (C1) controls in Latin-1 Supplement, and also plenty of printing characters.

Now we can `cat -v` it:

```
^@^A^B^C^D^E^F^G^H
^K^L^M^N^O^P^Q^R^S^T^U^V^W^X^Y^Z^[^\^]^^^_ !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;
<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~^?
M-BM-^@M-BM-^AM-BM-^BM-BM-^CM-BM-^DM-BM-^EM-BM-^FM-BM-^GM-BM-^HM-BM-^I
M-BM-^JM-BM-^KM-BM-^LM-BM-^MM-BM-^NM-BM-^OM-BM-^PM-BM-^QM-BM-^RM-BM-^S
M-BM-^TM-BM-^UM-BM-^VM-BM-^WM-BM-^XM-BM-^YM-BM-^ZM-BM-^[M-BM-^\M-BM-^]
M-BM-^^M-BM-^_M-BM- M-BM-!M-BM-"M-BM-#M-BM-$M-BM-%M-BM-&M-BM-'M-BM-(M-B
M-)M-BM-*M-BM-+M-BM-,M-BM--M-BM-.M-BM-/M-BM-0M-BM-1M-BM-2M-BM-3M-BM-4M-B
M-5M-BM-6M-BM-7M-BM-8M-BM-9M-BM-:M-BM-;M-BM-<M-BM-=M-BM->M-BM-?M-CM-^@
M-CM-^AM-CM-^BM-CM-^CM-CM-^DM-CM-^EM-CM-^FM-CM-^GM-CM-^HM-CM-^IM-CM-^J
M-CM-^KM-CM-^LM-CM-^MM-CM-^NM-CM-^OM-CM-^PM-CM-^QM-CM-^RM-CM-^SM-CM-^T
M-CM-^UM-CM-^VM-CM-^WM-CM-^XM-CM-^YM-CM-^ZM-CM-^[M-CM-^\M-CM-^]M-CM-^^
M-CM-^_M-CM- M-CM-!M-CM-"M-CM-#M-CM-$M-CM-%M-CM-&M-CM-'M-CM-(M-CM-)M-C
M-*M-CM-+M-CM-,M-CM--M-CM-.M-CM-/M-CM-0M-CM-1M-CM-2M-CM-3M-CM-4M-CM-5M-C
M-6M-CM-7M-CM-8M-CM-9M-CM-:M-CM-;M-CM-<M-CM-=M-CM->
```

(I've wrapped that manually so that it's readable)

You can see that it represents U+0080 at the start of the fourth line, which is UTF-8 `C2 80`, as `M-BM-^@`. `M-B` represents the C2 byte: B is 0x42, so `M-` represents setting the high bit (i.e. adding 0x80). `M-^@` is doing the same for a null byte (meta-ctrl-@) - the `M-x` and `^x` notation is combined together.

The same thing will happen for all non-ASCII codepoints, which will consist entirely of high bytes in UTF-8, or all bytes 128-255 in any other encoding. Different `cat` implementations may have their own behaviour as `-v` [is not](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cat.html) a standard `cat` option, but both GNU cat and the common BSD versions behave this way.